# unable to run PyQt4 example

Tags: python, cygwin, pyqt4

I am trying to run a pyqt4 example through Notepad++. I asked this question earlier ([Nothing happens when running PyQt4 example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380923/nothing-happens-when-running-pyqt4-example-code)), and ended up uninstalling Enthought Canopy and all remnants of python and installing cygwin. Now, when I run the example code I get the following error from npp's console. nppExec command --> `C:\cygwin\bin\python2.7.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. The example code is shown all the way at the bottom.

The closest I can get is to start cygwin x (type startx from the bash shell) where I can get the example window to come up, although I am unable to exit out of the window.

I feel like I am in over my head here, I just want to create some simple GUI's and I am struggling just to get an example to work. Does Cygwin's python installation lack the classic IDLE?

```
C:\cygwin\bin\python2.7.exe -i "C:\Users\Brian\Dropbox\Python\PYqt_practice.py"
Process started >>>
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Brian\Dropbox\Python\PYqt_practice.py
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Brian/Dropbox/Python/PYqt_practice.py
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
C:\Users\Brian\Dropbox\Python\PYqt_practice.py: cannot connect to X server 
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

PyQt4 example code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you try run it with that Preferred POSIX equivalent path instead of `C:\Users\Brian\Dropbox\Python\PYqt_practice.py`?

Comment: I have given up on running it in cygwin for now. I am extremely confused. I have reinstalled python and added everything from scratch for now (numpy, pyqt4, matplotlib) and am able to successfully run the example, but only from IDLE, not when executed from npp

Answer (score 0):

PyQT4 and PyQT5 installed with Cygwin emulate directly what their equivalent Linux packages do, meaning they **do** expect you to run an X server. Packages dedicated to Windows obviously don't.

Basically you have two choices:

1. Give up on Cygwin and use packages dedicated to Windows, that don't need X server. (You could also run non-Cygwin python in Cygwin environment, but that's going to cause you some headaches, for example with Unicode.)
2. Install X server for Cygwin like this:

   1. Get `xorg-server` package
   2. Run `startx`

   If this causes you problems, try:

   2. Run `xwin -multiwindow` instead of `startx`

   Now an icon should appear in your tray.

   3. Click it with right mouse button
   4. Hover to "applications"
   5. Click `xterm`.

   Congratulations! You just ran an `xterm` shell in X environment. See if your application works now.